# Why did the writing process fails when using dockerfile to install Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I want to know why I cannot write data into Apache IoTDB? I refer to the install process in the official guide of IoTDB and use the dockerfile set mentioned. Except for setting the docker to our private data warehouse, other configuration is exactly the same. Wonder why the writing process is not successful, can someone offer a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docker used in Apache IoTDB has been processed to be compatible, so it is not possible to directly use your own private docker. If you want to build your private docker environment, you can use the `shell` script in the docker directory.